# DPKG Issues. Hangs, and won't let me run any commands

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Ubuntu randomlly decided to install this huge batch of updates today and I let it.

It froze however midway. I gave it an extra hour with no progress at all so I killed it and forced a hard restart.

Now whenever I try to do anything using DPKG's such as installing a new program, I get the error that

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Not a problems so I run it.....but then it hangs for a long time every time it runs into this part:

I've already tried that --configure -a command and that hangs as well.

> Generating grub configuration file ...

```
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
```

I've tried commands like sudo-apt-get install -f, the autoremove packages command and others but none seem to work?

EDIT:
I've now gotten past that to where sudo apt-get update will work.. and it won't hang anymore...but no programs can install. Ubuntu Software Center just keeps on saying Applying Changes.....

EDIT:
SOLVED!
https://www.swiftbyte.com/articles/linux/grub-configuration-hangs-during-kernel-update-on-ubuntu-running-in-hyper-v

It has to do with stuff I did on my other hard drives that aren't Linux related.

Comment: and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Yep, already tried that. Does the same thing. Hangs once it encounters that file

Comment: You should always copy the relevant content from links. your url https://www.swiftbyte.com/articles/linux/grub-configuration-hangs-during-kernel-update-on-ubuntu-running-in-hyper-v is today dead and I would have been very interested :(

Comment: Post your solution **as an answer** and ***not*** as an edit to the question. . Also the link is dead.